# How to split value from one input and then calculate it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, calculator

I have 2 inputs.
First - input, second - output.

User number up to 200 is counted $4 per user, therefore, if I type 20 users I see 80 in the second  input.

User number from 201 up to 500 is calculated assuming first 200 are paid $4 per user and every extra one is $1. Therefore, if I type 300 users, it counts 200 x $4 then adds 100 x $1, where total is 900.

User number from 501 up to 1000 is counted $0.50 per user. Therefore, if I type in 555 users, it counts 200 x $4 plus 300 x $1 plus 55 x $0.50. Total is 1127.50.

All the numbers above 1000 users are calculated at $0,25 rate.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function updatePrice() {
    var price = parseFloat($('#users-count').val());
    if (price <= '200') {
      var total = price * 4;
    } else if (price >= '201' && price <= '500') {
      var total = price * 1;
    } else if (price >= '501' && price <= '1000') {
      var total = price * 0.5;
    } else if (price >= '1000') {
      var total = price * 0.25;
    }
    var total = total.toFixed(0);
    $('#users-price').val(total);
  }
  $(document).on('change, keyup', '#users-count', updatePrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator-price-field">
  <input type="number" id="users-count" class="calculator-field" value="1" min="1"><span class="calculator-field-label">users</span>
</div>
<div class="calculator-price-field">
  <input type="number" id="users-price" class="calculator-field" value="1" min="1"><span class="calculator-field-label">USD/month</span>
</div>
```

[This is my codepen](https://codepen.io/Frunky/pen/WzEVZe)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate each value, like:

I also added/updated:

= `.toFixed(2);` - So that you can have decimal points. Your expected value has decimal points.

= Added a condition, if `total` does not exist, clear the textbox

```js
function updatePrice() {
  var price = parseFloat($('#users-count').val());

  if (price <= '200') {
    var total = price * 4;
  } else if (price >= '201' && price <= '500') {
    var total = (200 * 4) + ((price - 200));
  } else if (price >= '501' && price <= '1000') {
    var total = (200 * 4) + (300 * 1) + ((price - 500) * .5);
  } else if (price >= '1001') {
    var total = (200 * 4) + (300 * 1) + (500 * .5) + ((price - 1000) * .25);
  }
  var total = total.toFixed(2);

  if (total) $('#users-price').val(total);
  else $('#users-price').val("");
}
$(document).on('change, keyup', '#users-count', updatePrice);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator-price-field">
  <input type="number" id="users-count" class="calculator-field" value="1" min="1"><span class="calculator-field-label">users</span>
</div>
<div class="calculator-price-field">
  <input type="number" id="users-price" class="calculator-field" value="1" min="1"><span class="calculator-field-label">USD/month</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Eddie! Looks simple, but I couldn't  guess that. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The right syntax for binding multiple events is to put space between them.

Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function updatePrice() {
    var price = parseFloat($('#users-count').val());
    console.log(price);
    if (price <= '200') {
      var total = price * 4;
    } else if (price >= '201' && price <= '500') {
      var total = price * 1;
    } else if (price >= '501' && price <= '1000') {
      var total = price * 0.5;
    } else if (price >= '1000') {
      var total = price * 0.25;
    }
    var total = total.toFixed(0);
    $('#users-price').val(total);
  }
  $(document).on('change keyup', '#users-count', updatePrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator-price-field">
  <input type="number" id="users-count" class="calculator-field" value="1" min="1"><span class="calculator-field-label">users</span>
</div>
<div class="calculator-price-field">
  <input type="number" id="users-price" class="calculator-field" value="1" min="1"><span class="calculator-field-label">USD/month</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to find right way to calculate values as discussed in topic

Answer (score 1):

Calculate for each range separately. Also, you need to check whether total exists at the end in order to avoid `Uncaught TypeError` when the user removes the value in the input field.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function updatePrice() {
    var price = parseFloat($('#users-count').val());
    var total = 0;
    if (price <= '200') {
      total = price * 4;
    } else if (price >= '201' && price <= '500') {
      total = 800 + (price - 200) * 1;
    } else if (price >= '501' && price <= '1000') {
      total = 1000 + (price - 500) * 0.5;
    } else if (price >= '1000') {
      total = 1250 + (price - 1000) * 0.25;
    }
    total = total ? total.toFixed(0) : 0;
    $('#users-price').val(total);
  }
  $(document).on('change, keyup', '#users-count', updatePrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calculator-price-field">
  <input type="number" id="users-count" class="calculator-field" value="1" min="1"><span class="calculator-field-label">users</span>
</div>
<div class="calculator-price-field">
  <input type="number" id="users-price" class="calculator-field" value="1" min="1"><span class="calculator-field-label">USD/month</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this great idea!